# compare a string in a file line by line in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have writ tern the following code to check if the user input string is present is in the file. The method is **checkinfile**. I am using while loop to read line by line and do .eql? to check if its matching.
But even when i enter a matching value, the method returns false. Can someone help me with this please?

```
    class School
    #Declaration of Global Variable. The file is the file database used for storing names of the students.
    $filename="studentsdatabase"
    #All the methods for the class Student are declared in this area

    #Method : Show Menu
      def showmenu
        puts "\e[H\e[2J"
        print "*" * 100
        print "\n"
        print "-"*44 + "MENU OPTIONS" +"-"*44 + "\n"
        print "*" * 100
        print "\n"
        print "1. Add a student data\n"
        print "2. Verify if the student is present in the database\n"
        print "3. View the list of students in the database"
        print "Enter your option(1/2) :"
        option=gets.chomp.to_i
        return option
      end

    #Method : Ask the details of the students
      def askdetails
        puts "\e[H\e[2J"
        print "How many students are there\n"
        n = gets.chomp.to_i - 1
        print "Enter names one by one\n"
        names=Array.new(n)
        for i in (0..n)
          names[i]=gets.chomp
        end
        return names,n
      end

      def showdetails(names,n)
        for i in (0..n)
          puts names[i]
        end
      end

    #Method : Write into file database
      def write2file(names,n)
      studnamesfile=File.open($filename,"a")
        for i in (0..n)
         studnamesfile.puts names[i]
        end
      end

    #Method : This method verifies the user input in the file database.
      def checkinfile
        puts "\e[H\e[2J"
        print "Enter the name of the student: "
        studname=gets.chomp
        somefile=File.open($filename,"r")
        counter=1
        occur=0
        while(line=somefile.gets)
          val = puts.eql? studname
           occur=occur+1
        puts "#{counter}: #{line}"
        puts "#{val}"
        counter = counter + 1
      end
        somefile.close

      end
    #This is the end of Class Student declaration
    end

    #Main Program starts here
    stud=School.new
    option=stud.showmenu
    if option==1
    names,n = stud.askdetails
    stud.write2file(names,n)
    else
    puts "\e[H\e[2J"
    stud.checkinfile
    end
```

Comment: Now that your code is working, you might consider posting it at SO's sister-site, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), to get suggestions for improvements. Your code is very un-Ruby-like now, so you might find that helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line which contains `eql?`:

```
val = puts.eql? studname
```

Here you check if the return value of calling the method `puts` equals `studname`. `puts` always returns `nil`, so, `val` will probably always be `false`.

To fix it, you should have used `line`:

```
val = line.eql? studname
```

Also, you might want to make sure there are no trailing newlines to affect your test:

```
val = line.strip.eql? studname.strip
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Uri. i had committed both the mistakes u said. Now its working